The most appropriate filetype for fail2ban configuration files?
When opening any file fail2ban configuration file, it typically gets detected as having the conf filetype due those files .conf filename suffix. The fileformat is explained in detail in jail.conf(5), but I see no highlevel description of what the format used is called. Neither do I find any relevant hits if searchin the web or on vim.org for a filetype plugin.
With the syntax highlighting leaving a bit to be desired, I wonder whether there is a more appropriate filetype to use in vim?

I would use the toml filetype for fail2ban configuration files.
You could use the following modeline at the end of your configuration file to help Vim discovering the correct filetype to use:
# vim: ft=toml

Or alternatively, as suggested by @sampi:
autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/fail2ban/**/*conf setfiletype toml


Alternatively au BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/fail2ban/**/*conf setfiletype toml can be added config.

@sampi consider turning your comment into a proper answer.

That autocommand really belongs in ~/.vim/ftdetect/…, and since toml is used in the runtime's filetype.vim a PR to add the detection is probably welcome.
